# Why isn't my webapp2 import / Google App Engine "Hello, World" working?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

While I'm able to get my "Hello, World" program running on Google App Engine (GAE), it only works when I create a version that doesn't rely on the webapp2 import. Why isn't the import working? What I need to do to fix it?

Version of helloworld.py that works:

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, World!!'
```

Version of helloworld.py that does not work:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

This second version renders as a blank page.

I think the problem is that the webapp2 import isn't working. When I run python from within the same directory as my hello world program from the command line I get the following:

```
Brians-MacBook-Air-2:app_engine_hello_world brian$ python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import webapp2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named webapp2
```

However, I see webapp2.py in the following directory:

```
Brians-MacBook-Air-2:webapp2 brian$ pwd
/Users/brian/Repos/app_engine_hello_world/build/webapp2
```

Also, I'm running python 2.7 installed in the following location:

```
Brians-MacBook-Air-2:app_engine_hello_world brian$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

EDIT: Adding my app.yaml file & some other potentially useful info...

```
application: hello-world-cs253
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

I'm using version 1.7.0 - 2012-06-26 of the SDK / GAE Launcher

Results are the same in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari

Comment: What's in your `app.yaml`? What browser are you using? Are you using the SDK? Which version? If `/Users/brian/Repos/app_engine_hello_world/build` is not in your `PYTHON_PATH`, then it won't import. To check it `echo $PYTHON_PATH` or within the Python REPL `import sys` and `print sys.path`.

Comment: @bossylobster - Thanks for your follow-up questions and suggestions.  They are very much appreciated.  I've edited my question above to include my `app.yaml`, browser, and SDK info.  Using IDLE, I confirmed that `/Users/brian/Repos/app_engine_hello_world/build` is NOT in my PYTHON_PATH.  Can you tell me how to add directories to PYTHON_PATH?  Is it the same as adding to $PATH?  Sorry if this a rookie question.

Comment: If you're not running on actual app engine or dev_appserver, I'm guessing that you probably don't need webapp2. Try a conditional import. USE_APP_ENGINE = False if USE_APP_ENGINE: import webapp2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to install webapp2. When you run the dev_appserver.py with the path to your project directory as the argument, it handles the importing of `webapp2`.

Do you have a app.yaml in place, and is it correct?

For Python2.7 you need to specify that you're using Python2.7. Runtime should be python27

```
application: your_app
version: 1
runtime: python27    #important
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: your_app.py
```

What command are you running to run your program?

Do this -

```
you@your-computer:~/GAE_folder$ python dev_appserver.py /path/to/your/project/directory
```

And then open `localhost:8080` on your browser.

**EDIT -**

I think I know what the problem is. It happened to me too when I first tried out the example given on the site.

Add this bit of code to your `helloworld.py` file at the end -

```
def main():
    app.run()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I appreciate them.  I edited my question to include the info you asked about.  I've been using GoogleAppEngineLauncher to run and deploy my app.  As far as I can tell, the GAE Launcher app was all that was installed when I downloaded the SDK.  `$ python dev_appserver.py` from the command line gives 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'dev_appserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`  Thanks for any other suggestions you may have!

Comment: Your suggestion worked!  Thanks!  I probably need to spend more time reviewing the webapp2/GAE documentation, but it's odd that this code snippet isn't more obvious.  Maybe the problem is specific to our set-up (?).  If you happen to remember where you originally found it and can post the link, I'll follow-up there to get more info.  Thanks again!

Comment: It's somewhere in the documentation. Probably in the 2.5 documentation. Though it should be obvious that you need to do something with the app. Just defining it and it's classes won't do anything.

Comment: You only need the `__name__` boilerplate in Python 2.5. If you switch to using Python 2.7 and enable threadsafe, your code will work as-is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is within your **app.yaml**:

```
  script: helloworld.py
```

When using the `python27` runtime, you must change it to:

```
  script: helloworld.app
```

The solution suggested above seems to work, but strictly speaking this is the right way to do it. Using a main function is unnecessary and deprecated.